# How to add a UISearchController to the navigation bar of my iOS app in the Storyboard?

Tags: ios

I'd like to know how can I drag and drop a `UISearchController` and add it on the top of a `UINavigationBar` instead of doing it programmatically:

```
var searchController: UISearchController!
var searchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController!

searchResultsTableViewController = UITableViewController()
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsTableViewController)
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

Dragging from the objects library and placing it on the navigation bar does not add it to the bar, but places it to the center of the view. How do I add a `UISearchController` to the navigation bar of my app?

Comment: add UISearchBar instead of SearchBarController

Comment: Thanks @engmahsa, I can't seem to add to the navigation bar neither `UISearchBar` and `UISearchBarController`.

Comment: Embed your view Controller in Navigation Controller to have navigation bar at first , or if you push from another view navigation bar will automatically create. What is your case exactly?

Comment: My `UIViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I tried to add the search bar both in the views but it couldn't be attached to the navigation bars.

Comment: You cant add search bar to navigationbar . Just navigation item has navitionitem.title i mean that you can assign a custom view just to navigation item.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @engmahsa. So there is basically no way to accomplish what I've asked?

Comment: Alloc init a searchbar in a custom Uiview then assign that UIVIEW to inavigationitem.title

Comment: I dont think so but if you find a way please inform tnx

Comment: I guess you're right, feel free to post an answer based on your comments. I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know we can just assign a custom view to navigationitem.title not to navigationbar , and there is no way to add the view from storyBoard. You can alloc init an UIView and add sub view the search bar to it. Then assign this UIView to navigationItem.title